# Ionic React Android, unable to get access token after redirect

Tags: ionic-framework, msal.js, ionic-react, msal-react, msal

I'm using @ to get access token from azure ad b2c but I'm facing issues in android. in android it's showing error that **Unable to complete authorization as there is no interactive call in progress. This can be due to closing the app while the authorization was in process**.

my code ...

```
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonApp, IonButton, IonRouterOutlet, setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import {AuthenticatedTemplate, MsalProvider, UnauthenticatedTemplate } from '@azure/msal-react';
import {loginRequest, msalConfig } from "./msalConfig";
import { EventType, InteractionRequiredAuthError, PublicClientApplication} from '@azure/msal-browser';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';


setupIonicReact();

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const App: React.FC = () => {


async ()=>{
  await msalInstance.initialize();
  await msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise(); 
  
}

const handleLogin = async () => {
  await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
}


  return(
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <IonApp>

      <div>
        <IonButton onClick={() => handleLogin()}>
          Login
        </IonButton>
      </div>
      {/* <div>
    <AuthHandlerComponent />
    </div> */}
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <h3>
          Successfully Logged In
        </h3>
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <h3>
          Login Data not found
        </h3>
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
      </IonApp>
      </MsalProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

```
/**
 * Enter here the user flows and custom policies for your B2C application
 * To learn more about user flows, visit: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview
 * To learn more about custom policies, visit: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview
 */
 export const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: "B2C_1_signup",
        editProfile: "B2C_1_signup"
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: "https://rideorg.b2clogin.com/rideorg.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup"
        },
        editProfile: {
            authority: "https://rideorg.b2clogin.com/rideorg.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup"
        }
    }
}

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
 export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "c1c594aa-cfb6-4a6d-ae3d-6930b0d9d3bf",
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        redirectUri : "msalc1c594aa-cfb6-4a6d-ae3d-6930b0d9d3bf://auth",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/",
        //authorization_user_agent : "WEBVIEW"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage"
    }
};

// Scopes you add here will be prompted for consent during login
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["demo.read"]
};
```

[no signin details got from popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkeWc.png)

how to get the access token on to the android app after redirect?...any WORKING samples?...

IONIC REACT ANDROID